# Will a wix built installer run on .Net Core 2.0?

Tags: .net-core, wix

I looked over the wix website and it didn't speak to this question. Will a wix built installer run on .Net core (assuming no custom C++ code called)?

And if not, is there an alternative for .Net Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installers built using the WiX Toolset do not have any .NET dependency by default.  The only time you add a dependency is if you author a managed code custom action.  However, even then it's not typically an issue because pretty much every modern OS has some version of .NET built into it.  It's hard to imagine having .NET Core and not .NET in the desktop / server environment.   We aren't talking about microservers and containers where WiX is unlikely to be used.